# How should I define the contains() command for a LinkedList?

Tags: java, list, linked-list, contains

I currently am redefining the commands for a Linked list via recursion, where the public method takes in an object and calls the private contains() method which has a Node parameter but cannot seem to figure out the logic.

```
@Override
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    if (o.equals(contains(o))) {
        return true;
    }

    contains(o);
    return false;
}

private boolean contains(Node node) {
    if (node.next == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (node == node.next) {
        return true;
    }

    return contains(node.next);
}
```

Comment: One problem would seem to be the condition `node == node.next` in your private method. It checks whether the argument `node` is equal to its `next` node, which is probably not what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are constrained to use recursion (not iteration), let's look at what you would need here:

1. **Private recursive method**

Recursive method must have a base case and a recursive call for a subproblem (in this case the rest of the list).

a) **Base Case**: In the base case here, you would either find the node with the expected key, or reach the end of the list, something like:

```java
if (node == null) {
    return false;
}

if (key.equals(node.key)) {
    return true;
}
```

b) **Recursive Call**: You must call the method with the `next` node (rest of the list).

```java
return contains(key, node.next);
```

Putting both the things together, you would get the following method:

```java
private boolean contains(Object key, Node node) {

    if (node == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (key.equals(node.key)) {
        return true;
    }

    return contains(key, node.next);
}
```

2. **Public method**

The public method just takes a key and invokes the recursive method with node pointed to the head of the list.

```
@Override
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    returns contains(o, this.head);
}
```

It would be helpful if you practice a few simple problems on recursion following the above template, just to get a hang of things.